# How can I execute multiple php files through one cron job and a loop

Tags: php, while-loop, cron, scheduled-tasks

This is my cronjob.php file and in mysql database I have a `row['cronjob']` and its value is `test1.php` and that is just the name of one of my php files that need to be executed when datetime row equal or less than current time, while the cron job runs.
I thought I can do a `while-loop` then get the name of the file from the `cronjob row` and then execute it if the datetime is equal or less then current time when the corn job runs. Please see below:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $detime = strtotime($row['date']);
      $id = $row['id'];
      $phpfile = $row['cronjob'];

            if($detime <= time()){
                  include $phpfile;
                  $sql2 = "UPDATE my-table SET cronstatus = 1 WHERE id = $id ";
                  $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
             } 
  }
```

However, I've got an error `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean` as soon as include `include $phpfile;` (before that the loop runs with no error!. By adding include to the code, only first row is going to be executed (while there is an error!) and while-loop does not do its job. What is the best way to execute all of my php files by using one cron job that runs every x-minutes based on checking the datetime against the current time?
Appreciate if you can write down the right code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you change tactic a little. Consider the following file structure:

- /jobs
- /jobs/JobInterface.php
- /jobs/MyFirstJob.php
- /jobs/MySecondJob.php
- /jobs/<.. more jobs ..>
- /cron.php

Each file that ends in Job in the jobs folder contain a class that implements the [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) found in JobInterface.php. This interface requires all Jobs to have a "run" method.

You then either use [autoloading](http://phpenthusiast.com/blog/how-to-autoload-with-composer) or you simply include all the files in the jobs folder manually at the top of cron.php, which is still the file you run.

In the "cronjob" field in your database, you would have the name of the job (i.e. class name), not the name of file.

```
$job_class_name = $row['cronjob'];
if (false === class_exists($job_class_name)) throw new Exception("No such job");
$job = new $job_class_name;
if (false === $job instance JobInterface) throw new Exception("Not a job");
$job->run(); // since the interface requires all jobs to have this method
```